# JS function cancelFullScreen don't work after pressing F11. Is it possible to fix it?

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, fullscreen

This is source code for exit from fullscreen mode:

```
var cancelFullScreen = document.webkitCancelFullScreen || document.mozCancelFullScreen;
cancelFullScreen.call(document);
```

it's works correctly when i enter fullscreen using function startFullScreen, but don't work after pressing F11 key - browser won't exit fullscreen mode. Browsers Chrome 18 and Firefox 12. Why it's happens? Is it bug, security restriction or some other? Is it possible to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>F11</kbd> and `requestFullScreen` are the different things in browsers. `requestFullScreen` requires permissions from users while pressing <kbd>F11</kbd> is not.

Also as you may see they have different interface. For example opening window in fullscreen mode (using JS) in Google Chrome don't tell user that he can go out pressing <kbd>F11</kbd> while *native* fullscreen do.

Comment: With all due respect, how it answered to my question? What is about cancelFullScreen?

Comment: The answer is no, you can't fire `cancelFullScreen` method if fullscreen was opened using F11

Answer (score 0):

Your example makes no sense, because you can only request full screen on an element, not on a document. The API also requires you to cancel full screen on the element on which you requested full screen. The Gecko API also tells you the element that it thinks is in full screen mode, i.e. the one that you need to cancel full screen on. If you press <kbd>F11</kbd> to enter full screen, this element remains null, because you cannot cancel it.

Comment: What? I thought you could only fullscreen an element but you had to cancel full screen on the document element.

Comment: @gengev Sorry, you're right about cancelling full screen on the document, but you still have to have a full screen element in order to be able to do that.